# Google Drive download limit / throttle on individual file downloadUrls?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm seeing a 403 "Access to the webpage was denied" error on one specific file being accessed via the Drive SDK. It was working earlier, the app permissions are set correctly, and we're having success with other files using different tokens against the same app.

We're getting the downloadUrl from the SDK successfully, then seeing the error message only after users are redirected to the downloadUrl. Because of that it's hard to track, but we've confirmed that it's working for some, but not for others — it hasn't fully stopped.

The full error text is:

> Access to the webpage was denied
>   You are not authorized to access the webpage at [...] You may need to sign in.
>   HTTP Error 403 (Forbidden): The server refused to fulfill the request.

We're including the GET download and (valid) access_token parameters, all that.

My question is this: could this be related to the reported Google Drive outage that's currently happening, or is there some sort of throttle/limit to access of a single file over the drive API? I've never seen this behavior before, and this response isn't listed among the standard 403 responses.

Comment: Is this fixed? It could have been due to the outage, but seems unlikely.

Comment: Hard to tell. It only affected one specific file on one specific account. Everything was working fine, it spiked from low/no traffic to (sustained) 2 or 3 downloads per minute, was doing fine, then after something in the order of 500 downloads we started seeing the 403. It never reported as an error on our end so it's hard to tell exactly when it began. We transitioned to an S3 resource to ride out the spike, haven't seen it since — that file or any other.

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen something similar. I was using a freshly acquired access token, so I don't think it's oauth related. My working theory is that the downloadUrl link was stale. When I got fresh meta data, which had a different value in downloadUrl, it worked using the same access token that had previously failed.

This is only a theory since it isn't documented anywhere, and I would actually expect 410 (or even 301) as a much more appropriate status than 403.